# Run "ping" command when link button is clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net, command-line

I am trying to pop up a Windows Command prompt and run a ping command when a link button is clicked. Link button looks something like:

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lbFTPIP" OnCommand="lbFTPIP_OnCommand" CommandArgumnet="1.2.3.4" Text="1.2.3.4"/>
```

I tried this for OnCommand:

```
protected void lbFTPIP_OnCommand(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    string sFTPIP = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
    string sCmdText = @"ping -a " + sFTPIP;
    Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = sCmdText; 
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
    p.Start();
}
```

When I click the link, it opens the command prompt but does not display or execute the command, it just shows the current directory. Not sure what I am missing here.

It is part of a web page, if this makes a difference.

Comment: Regarding the `cmd` command: you need to have `/C` (or `/K`) as the first argument (before `ping`) to signify that you want to run a command.

Comment: That was it! Thank you. I was missing /C. Is there a way to allow user to close the window? Right now it closes after displaying responses to ping command> I tried p.WaitForExit() but it is not good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to open a console and immediately run a command, you need to use either the `/C` or `/K` switch:

```
// Will run the command and then close the console.
string sCmdText = @"/C ping -a " + sFTPIP;

// Will run the command and keep the console open.
string sCmdText = @"/K ping -a " + sFTPIP;
```

If you want to institute a "Press any key", you can add a `PAUSE`:

```
// Will run the command, wait for the user press a key, and then close the console.
string sCmdText = @"/C ping -a " + sFTPIP + " & PAUSE";
```

---

EDIT:

It would probably be best to redirect your output and then display the results separately:

```
Process p = new Process();
// No need to use the CMD processor - just call ping directly.
p.StartInfo.FileName = "ping.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "-a " + sFTPIP; 
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();

var output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

// Do something the output.
```

Comment: Thank you. /K works perfect. When I try this on the server, it works perfectly. When I publish the site and run it from my workstation, using IE or Chrome, command prompt window does not show. I tried on different machine and get the same thing.

Comment: @NoBullMan - Well you may not be able to launch from end user machines due to the protection level of browsers. It would be a huge security risk if a browser could open a console on your machine and run a command. This type of behavior (why it works on your server) would be more for "control panel" type applications. If you want to review the output you should redirect the output. I'll update the answer with this.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to find some other way of letting the user know his ping test worked or not; maybe run the command in silent mode, without opening the command prompt window, and get the result and show it to user in Ajax pop up control. It is an Intranet app. If I don't specify /C or /K, will it prevent the command prompt from opening?

Comment: Works fine in server when I redirect the output.

Comment: @NoBullMan - Sorry, I flip-flopped the wait and capture commands. Answer updated. The command above should run on the server, so as long as the app pool has the ability run shell commands then the `output` variable should contain the results of the ping which you can display back to your users.

Comment: Thank you for all the help Jason. It is much appreciated.

Comment: @NoBullMan - Glad to help. Best of luck with your project.

Comment: Just more more quick question: is it possible to not show the command prompt at all, even when it briefly pops up with the title "C:\Windows\System32\ping.exe"?

Comment: @NoBullMan - Set `p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to execute cmd.exe, just execute ping.exe instead.

```
string sCmdText = @"-a " + sFTPIP;
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "ping.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = sCmdText;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
p.Start();
```

Also, don't set `UseShellExecute = false` unless you intend to redirect the output, which I'm surprised you are not doing.

Comment: Users want to be able to click the IP address link and make sure it is responding. However, if I wanted to redirect the output, how would I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

First thing is that you have something strange here `CommandArgumnet="1.2.3.4"` that is misspelled. The other thing is the /C and a space before ping.

Comment: it is just a sample. The actual IP address is real address.

Comment: I mean that you have `CommandArgumnet` instead of `CommandArgument`.